# What size of HTTP response is considered huge?

Tags: java, rest

I have created a RestAPI using Java Spring:

```
@PostMapping("/test/{testCode}")
    public @ResponseBody String execute(@RequestBody String test, @PathVariable int testCode) {
        return service.execute(testCode, test);
    }
```

Basically, I am sending the content of a file as a String output. The max size of the file can be 100KB.
I have two questions:

1. Is 100KB too much size for a String data type?
2. Is 100KB considered a huge response and should be sent as chunks or should it be sent in a single shot?

Comment: what devices / environment? What problems do you envisage?

Comment: It is a plain REST API exposed in a web-app that processes the input fed by the user to generate an output that can be of max 100KB size. This will mostly be consumed by the end-users from their PCs. I am okay with a 2sec delay for the response but not more than that.

Comment: Answers: no, no, and it doesn't matter.   Although "considered" implies that you are asking for an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. String can hold data of size 2^31 - 1. 100KB is not too much. But if you are serving multiple simultaneous REST requests and generating several Strings with such size, it might cause memory overload (depending on your server's hardware capabilities).
2. There is no limit on Response.

Comment: @ruakh You are right. I was thinking of Request. I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing out :)